# rsync and caching issues (flush data immediately?)

Tags: linux, freeze, rsync, cache

I have challenges copying data from external HDD to storage server using **rsync**.

Here's my setup:

1. Using Linux Mint as my OS
2. I attach an external HDD (USB).
3. I mount (webdav) to a storage server located outside my network
4. Using rsync, I copy data from the external HDD to the storage server.
5. rsync finish "copying" *very* quickly.
6. ...and then my desktop starts hanging.

I assume this is because rsync copies data to cache/memory, and it's then actually flushed to the storage box in the background.

I would like to avoid this flush. How do I know if the copying of data did actually finish? When rsync finish, I would like he copying to have been done...

I'm running rsync as follows:

`rsync -c -t -r -v /media/abc/ExternalHDD/somePath/ /media/backup-server/ExternalHDD/somePath/`

I guess there's a simple solution, but after googling I didn't come any nearer (trying: `nocache rsync ...` didn't help).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation the userspace davfs mount helper does the caching, not rsync. Feel free to try with simple `cp` command and you'll see the same effect.

The solution can be to set up rsync server on storage, and uses this to bypass the caching `mount.davfs`.

Comment: yes, this is actually a 'sync' issue. webdav probably ignores nocache and maybe sync also. probably configurable at expense of very slow webdav responses. Try also nocache -n x where x is a number of nocache attempts it will make. See https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/nocache/nocache.1.en.html